# Encoding and Decoding Strings From Javascript to C# - Not Working

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, decode, encode

I am having an issue with some string encoding, maybe its a iis issue, or something i am overlooking. Basically, randomly, when users commit changes, the text gets stored with the %20, as if its completely ignoring my decode. It never happens to me on localhost, live, or with any browser; its never consistant, dont even know how to test what is going wrong.

*Just gonna paste the basic parts:*

**Text Control accepting user input**

```
<asp:TextBox TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server" txtActionUpdate"></asp:TextBox>
```

then

**Javascript "escape" and passed to ajax method to be sent to codebehind**

```
var tAction = escape(document.getElementById("txtActionUpdate").value);
```

then

**In the webmethod i decode with the following:**

```
Test = Microsoft.JScript.GlobalObject.unescape(tAction);
```

(Previously was: *Test = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(tAction);*)

But none the less both **decode** options above work perfectly (for me?). But randomly, when users are working on it, it will literally "skip" the decode step and just write it to the DB in its encoded format (ie: this%20is%20a%20Test%20string), as if i never had the code at all.

We have multiple customers (separate URL's) but one code base. During publish, i delete first then publish, clear app pools, get the users to clear browser cache (hate the latter actually), but this never seems to remain consistent. I have a feeling this is more some "caching" or "server settings" issue rather than a code problem... making me look bad! ;) lol. Anyone got some hunches?

Comment: Without seeing more code it's probably going to be impossible to help.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use `escape` for this (or anything else). I'd use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent), then decode with `HttpUtility.UrlDecode` (I think; MSDN is down right now, apparently).

Comment: The only section i been changing was the code behind decode methods. Always left the 'escape' as i assumed its fine. Seen quite a few forums mentioning to avoid 'escape' though, as the receiving server might not 'understand' certain chars. I am gonna try what you suggested; i've seen it before, just always thought its more for URL's, as apposed to just plain text (including / \ * + etc). Yay! ;)

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that somewhere on the client the data is encoded twice, which then leads to the effect you're seeing.